# I'm using python 3.8 and webbrowser isn't opening a url

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically I use python 3.8 and I am experimenting with the webbrowser functions so I decided to type up a simple program that will help me for the school year. When you type 0, it should open the link but it just doesn't. However, whenever I put just the webbrowser code in a new blank python code, it opens. Can you guys please tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
import webbrowser
def printgrid(printgrids):
    print("[Open Canvas] [Option 2] [Option 3]")
    print("    0            1          2")
    print("[Option 4]    [Option 5] [Option 6]")
    print("    3            4          5")
    print("[Option 7]    [Option 8] [Option 9]")
    print("    6            7          8")
    global option
    option = input("Select an option including the corresponding integer: ")
printgrid("print")
if option == 0:
    url = 'http://fcps.net/canvas'
    webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input()` function in Python gives you a *string,* not a number.

And, since `"0"` is not the same as `0`, the condition to the `if` statement will be false. You can see that with the following program and transcript:

```
pax:~> cat testprog.py
value = input("Please enter zero: ")
print(f"is numeric zero: {value == 0}")
print(f"is string zero:  {value == '0'}")

print(f"0 is {type(0)}")
print(f"'0' is {type('0')}")
print(f"value is {type(value)}")

pax:~> python testprog.py
Please enter zero: 0
is numeric zero: False
is string zero:  True
0 is <class 'int'>
'0' is <class 'str'>
value is <class 'str'>
```

The quickest solution is probably to change your `if` statement to:

```
if option == "0":
```

---

And, though it's not really related to your problem, I find that global variables are generally the *wrong* way to go for anything other than *very* simple code snippets. I think it's preferable to do something like:

```
def get_option():
    # print your menu grid
    return input("Select an option including the corresponding integer: ")

option = printgrid()
if option == 0:
    # open your web browser
```

Comment: LMAO I'm pretty new to python that was literally all I had to do thank you so much I've been at this for hours